# PerfView showing thousands of random FileOpenOrCreate during thread exhaustion

Tags: .net, performance, iis, cpu, perfview

Does anyone know why I am getting thousands of calls to FileOpenOrCreate looking for random .cshtml and .vbhtml files using PerfView and the Processes / Files / Registry stacks section of a collection?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you spend just a little bit time on the source code (but not obvious how to locate the source files), you can see ASP.NET runtime (`WebPageRoute`) is trying to map request path to file system path,

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/42991b3d2537b702736463f76a10a4fcf2ea44c9/src/System.Web.WebPages/WebPageRoute.cs#L35

In that process it utilizes a cache in `MapPathBasedVirtualPathProvider`,

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Hosting/MapPathBasedVirtualPathProvider.cs,78

The file system access recorded by PerfView matches the behavior of building up such a cache, so there doesn't seem to be anything wrong there.

Comment: Why is it searching a shared drive that has thousands of images?  That doesnt make sense.  Why is it using full URLS and treating that as a path?  I understand it matches the behavior but the folders its trying to do this on it not normal.

Comment: Only the developers of ASP.NET know what makes sense, so if you like, talk to them and see what they respond, https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues